# Prompt when copying multiple files?

Tags: command-line, cp

When copying multiple files from one directory to another is there a way to get bash to run through each file and ask for y/n? I vaguely remember adding something to the end of my command like 'ok?' to make it do this, but I can't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you’re remembering the `-ok` option to `find`. 
Try something like

```
find . -name pattern -ok cp {} other_directory \;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been driving me insane for the last hour!

Answer (score 1):

Use `-i` switch (interactive). It works for cp/mv/rm/...

Comment: But doesn't i switch work only when there is overwrite cases? I mean for normal copies, there will be no prompt to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I want it to prompt even for normal copies. I know it exists, I used it months ago when setting up my raspberry pi but I've forgotten it now!

Comment: In that case, just replace cp with echo to see what will get copied.